# DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, back-button, pushstate

I have ajax search based web (filter with inputs and results) where i want make working back/foward browser button. So i must use `window.history.pushState` witch is working with contetnt (search results) but i must 'store' whole filter with inputs and selected values.

On filter inputs i am using [SumoSelect](http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/sumoselect_demo.html) plugin and if you store all html elements to variable and after that append it back to DOM (after press back button) functionality of SumoSelect is not working any more...

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778812/sumoselect-input-remove-add-html-not-working-farthest) is my question about it. One possible solution (what i know) how make it works after append is use `.contents()` instead of `.html()`.

BUT if i use `.contents()` in `pushState` like this:

```
 window.history.pushState({"html":results,"filter": $('#filter').contents(),"pageTitle":"title"},"", null);
```

I get error:

> DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned.

So is there any options how store filter to state to make it work?

Answer (score 9):

The [pushState location state object must be serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method), which means no methods. $('#filter').contents() returns a jQuery object that can't be serialized.

Try turning the contents into an object or array.